# Imaginary energy integration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

Is it possible to solve the integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ixs}}{k^2-s^2}ds
$$

if it is known that $k^2$ has infinitesimal imaginary part (proportional to energy of a quantum particle)? Does it require the use of analytic integration, as would be possible if $k^2$ were real?

Comment: Have you tried using a contour integral?

Comment: Yes and understand how this works if k^2 is real, but I am unsure if this is possible or needed if k^2 complex, as the pole is no longer on the real line.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this query?

Comment: Why would it matter whether $k$ is complex or real?